# eternicode bootstrap-datepicker - add one day to senond date without moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I wanted to ask, if is possible to add one day to second datepicker, while selecting date in first datepicker.

Below some piece of code, part with comment, shows when this event is.
This code works fine, but i want to add one day, on first datepicker update.
Now this code update second datepicker with exact value of first one.
Is this possible without moment.js ?

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('.date-1').datepicker({
    startDate: now,
    onRender: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {

    startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));

// This code updates second datepicker, but should add + 1 day to this date.
    $('.date-2').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    $('.date-2').datepicker('setDate', startDate);


}).data('datepicker');
```